SET PYTHONPATH must always execute manually before script run
I have a machine installed with Python 3.5 and a script run failed due to error
[ERROR] Exception <class 'ImportError'>, No module named 'test_swlib'

The test_swlib.py is located in C:\Program Files\TestSW\mod
I found a workaround, which I have to set the pythonpath manually before script run.
SET PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\TestSW\mod

Once the machine restarted then script run is failed again without setting PYTHONPATH manually.
I have checked the system and user variable in Windows Environment is added with these string.
I do not know why I have to execute the setting command manually every time.
Please suggest how to fix this python environment problem.


in environment setting,set this path C:\Program Files\TestSW\mod instead of C:\Program Files

this is already set until the last folder path, not working still.
